# iOS startUpdatingLocation never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I've been trying to just get the location coordinates. After I call `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` nothing happens.

It never calls the `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;`

Any thoughts?

Notes: I have set the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and made my `CLLocationManager` of type `strong`. In my `viewDidLoad` I set my Delegate and I am trying to use `requestAlwaysAuthorization`.

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSLog(@"locationServicesEnabled: %@", [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] ? @"YES":@"NO");
    NSLog(@"locationManager init");
    NSLog(@"geocoder init");
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    //locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

    NSLog(@"locationManager startUpdatingLocation");
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"locationManager:manager");
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;
{
    NSLog(@"locations %@", locations);

    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }

    // Stop Location Manager
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    // Reverse Geocoding
    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            locationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",
                                 placemark.locality,
                                 placemark.administrativeArea];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];

}
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLGeocoder *geocoder;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLPlacemark *placemark;
```

**Log**

```
2014-09-24 08:18:39.783 appName[1201:130186] locationServicesEnabled: YES
2014-09-24 08:18:39.784 appName[1201:130186] locationManager init
2014-09-24 08:18:39.784 appName[1201:130186] geocoder init
2014-09-24 08:18:39.785 appName[1201:130186] locationManager startUpdatingLocation
```

I have also tried removing `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];` and it still didn't do anything.

Other notes: If I check the device settings/privacy, it indicates that my app does indeed have location permissions. All my `.h` properties are `@synthesize` properly in the `.m` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on iOS 8,  you need to  call either one of these methods :
`-[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]` or `-[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]` before calling `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` first.

You also need to have a description in your .plist for these keys `NSLocationUsageDescription`, `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`

Comment: I have `[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];`

Comment: My issue was that I needed to add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to the `.plist`.
I'm now getting location data. (albeit incorrect data, but I suspect that's a simulator thing.)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Location Manager is very broken in the current (Xcode 6.0.1) simulator.